# Xamarin iOS, Info.plist couldn't be opened

Tags: c#, ios, build, xamarin

I'm trying to build iOS project, but getting an error
"Info.plist could not be opened. An item with the same key has already been added"

I have no idea what I did wrong, can somebody help?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Picture is not good enough to see the error, but you aways can open Info.plist (actually it is a xml file) with some xml redactor and delete the item with same keys.